# How can I dynamically add a WTForms TextField to a FieldList using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, python, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I want to add or remove new WTForm input fields with button, using Jquery, just like here
http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/addremove-input-fields-dynamically-with-jquery/comment-page-1
but using my form-fields.

my form:

```
class EditBook(Form):
title = TextField('title', validators = [Required()])
authors = FieldList(TextField())
```

problem is that I can't just append for example

```
$(InputsWrapper).append("{{form.authors(size=20)}}");
```

it just prints this text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is based on nsfyn55's explanations (first paragraph).

I had a similar problem. The solution was to use:
https://github.com/Rhyzz/repeatable-fields

So, all you have to do is to look at the html snippet that is rendered by WTForms and use it as a 'template' in repeatable-fields plugin (see its [docs](https://github.com/Rhyzz/repeatable-fields/blob/master/README.md) for details)

Answer (score 10):

Your example conflates text generated server side with text you are appending in the browser using javascript. You **will not** be able to use the `{{ }}` syntax which is used by the server side templating engine. During rendering these are expanded and replaced with the HTML that is transmitted across the wire to the client. You will instead need to build the actual DOM elements that these built-in template functions would otherwise generate.

The DOM element you actually want to create looks like this:

```
<input id="authors-0" name="authors-0" type="text" value="Author Guy"></input>
<input id="authors-1" name="authors-1" type="text" value="Other Guy"></input>
```

This can then be encoded in a `multipart/form-data` stream that **WTForms** can work with. So your actually jQuery stuff needs to create a field looks something like this

```
$('<input>').attr({
    type: 'text',
    id: 'authors-' + index ,
    name: 'authors-' + index, 
    value: value
}).appendTo('form');
```

Where the `index` is the next positional index(this could be stored in a `data` attribute in a wrapping `ul`) and `value` is the value you want to assign to this box if any.

Additionally to get a feel for what `FieldList` renders you can run the code below from the command line. It will print the actual text that WTForms generates during the rendering process.

```
from wtforms import Form, TextField, FieldList
from webob.multidict import MultiDict

class TestForm(Form):
    authors = FieldList(TextField())

data_in = {'authors': ['Author Guy', 'Other Guy']}
test_form2 = TestForm(data=MultiDict(data_in))
print("HTML Render: %s" % test_form2.authors())
```

Comment: how can I iterate over this inputs in python?
or if I collect data using jquery, how can I send it to server?

Comment: seconding @user3684055 's question

Comment: When you bind the incoming data to a `TestForm` instance called `form` you should be able to loop over `form.authors.entries` - Here is some example code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30121763/how-to-use-a-wtforms-fieldlist-of-formfields

Comment: Okay, I see you have `data_in` and you have the `<input>` fields. I now have a button that can get clicked to generate a new `<input>`s. How do I now get to the `data_in` dict from my `<input>` fields? You just put the finished `data_in` dict there like it's totally clear how to read the N number of new `<input>`s  generated, but for me it's kind of not.
Could you clarify?

Comment: Never mind, you are using the dict to generate the text fields. 

Anyway, how do you get the data (into a dict) from the N `<input>` fields you create by running the javascript N times?

Comment: If you use the `name` html attribute and apply the correct indexing(`authors-0`, `authors-1`, etc.) the data will be in the correct format to instantiate `TestForm`. Serializing back and forth between HTML forms and WTForms `Form` instances is WTForms main job. All you have to worry about is getting your python code or your HTML form looking the way WTForms expects them to look. This answer describes how things should look when using `FieldList`

Answer (score 0):

I found `potar`'s suggestion useful. Here is an example of what using https://github.com/Rhyzz/repeatable-fields looks like.

```py
# from db import insert_row
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template_string
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms.fields import (
    StringField,
    EmailField,
    FieldList,
    FormField,
    SubmitField
)
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length
from wtforms import Form

# simplify rendering
# https://github.com/helloflask/bootstrap-flask
# pip install -U bootstrap-flask
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap5

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'fixme!'
Bootstrap5(app)

class StoreForm(Form): # IMPORTANT !!! Using FORM and not FLASKFORM avoids issues with CSRF tokens.
  store_name = StringField(
      "Store Name",
      validators=[DataRequired(), Length(2, 200)],
  )
  store_website = StringField(
      "Store Website",
      validators=[DataRequired(), Length(2, 200)],
  )

class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
  city_name = StringField(
      "City Name",
      validators=[DataRequired(), Length(2, 100)]
  )
  city_email = EmailField(
      "City Email",
      validators=[DataRequired(), Length(4, 100)],
  )
  stores = FieldList(
    FormField(StoreForm),
    label="Stores",
    min_entries=1, # Show 1 entry on a new form.
    max_entries=5, # Should a user submit over 5 stores, data will be cut off after 5 entries. We mitigate this through the client UI, but if a user uses other means to POST, their data will be lost.
  )
  submit = SubmitField("Submit")

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    """Register 1 to N stores."""
    form = RegistrationForm()
    
    print('Store entries:')
    for entry in form.stores.entries:
        print(entry.data) # how to access each store entry

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # insert_row(form.data) # save data
        print('Success')
        return redirect("/")

    return render_template_string(HTML_REGISTER, form=form)

HTML_REGISTER = """
{% from 'bootstrap5/form.html' import render_field %}

<h1>Registration Form</h1>

<form id="registration_form" action="/" method="post" novalidate>
  <h2>City Information</h2>
  <div>
    {{ render_field(form.city_name) }}
    {{ render_field(form.city_email) }}
  </div>

  <h2>Store Information</h2>
  <div class="rf_repeat">
    <div class="rf_wrapper">
      <div class="rf_container">
        {% for store in form.stores %}
          <div class="rf_template rf_row">
            {{ render_field(store.form.store_name) }} <!-- store.store_name works too -->
            {{ render_field(store.form.store_website) }}
              <div>
                <span class="rf_remove">Remove</span>
              </div>
          </div>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
        <div>
          <span class="rf_add">Add</span>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }} <!-- a single hidden_tag() call for the parent form -->
    {{ render_field(form.submit) }}
</form>
"""

app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5500, debug=True)
```

Now link the JS files to your layout template using something like,

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/registration_form.js') }}"></script>
```

```js
// /static/js/registration_from.js

// Copy and paste the jQuery script from https://github.com/Rhyzz/repeatable-fields/blob/master/repeatable-fields.js here.

// set the default jQuery selector configs
  self.default_settings = {
    wrapper: '.rf_wrapper',
    container: '.rf_container',
    row: '.rf_row',
    add: '.rf_add',
    remove: '.rf_remove',
    move: '.rf_move',
    move_up: '.rf_move-up',
    move_down: '.rf_move-down',
    move_steps: '.rf_move-steps',
    template: '.rf_template',
    is_sortable: false,
    before_add: null,
    after_add: self.after_add,
    before_remove: null,
    after_remove: self.after_remove,
    sortable_options: null,
    row_count_placeholder: '0', // This is the most important config as it aligns to WTForm <input> `name` attributes (e.g. store-0-store_name, store-1-store_name, ...).
  };

// if needed, modify the script
var STORE_COUNT = 0;
const MAX_STORE_COUNT = 2;
STORE_COUNT += 1;
if (STORE_COUNT >= MAX_STORE_COUNT ){
  alert('Max store count reached.');
  $('.rf_repeat .rf_add').hide();
}

// a possibly important edit to make would be to
// change the cloned and disabled input ids.
// You can use $(this).prop('id', '_' + this.id); beneath $(this).prop('disabled', true);
// You can use $(this).prop('id', this.id.substr(this.id.indexOf('_') + 1)); beneath $(this).prop('disabled', false);
```