# dynamic form in Flask

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

in a movie rating app,I would like to generate a WTF form in flask with dynamic number of fields. i.e, if there are three movies, there will be three fields.

I thought about a few options, but none of them worked:

```
class RatingForm(Form):
    rating = TextField("rating",[validators.Length(min=1, max=1)])
    movie_order=TextField("movie",[validators.Length(min=1, max=1)])
    submit = SubmitField("submit rating")
```

1. pass a parameter to the form object - I don't see how can I pass a parameter to this kind of class
2. make a loop inside the template, thus generate and return multiple forms, and choose the correct one. this also doesnt work, since the request.form is immutableDict, and I end up having multiple fields with the same key, which I cant access.

   > ```
   > {% for movie in movies_to_rate %}
   >   <p>
   >     <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/rate">
   >     {{ movie}}
   >     {{ forms[movie].rating}}
   >     {{ forms[movie].submit }}
   >     <input type="submit" value="Go">
   >
   > </p>  {% endfor %}
   > ```

any ideas about what can I do?

Comment: You can have fully dynamic control via [this](http://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specific_problems.html#dynamic-form-composition), but I don't know if there is not a better solution to your problem.

Comment: @syntonym thanks, but I was looking for something more related to flask...

Comment: A wild guess, but could you pass a list of form instances to the template?

Comment: Did you take a look at `FormField` in combination with `FieldList` like in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30121763/how-to-use-a-wtforms-fieldlist-of-formfields) ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can generate a list of TextField's as a class member instead of using one field object. (Though it looks a bit weird, I assume your validators are what you meant.)

```
class RatingForm(Form):
    def __init__(self, count):
        self.ratings = [TextField("rating_" + str(i), [validators.Length(min=1, max=1)])
                   for i in range(count)]
        ...
```