# How to make multiple buttons in Flask process them in separate way?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2, wtforms

I'm creating my very first web app with Flask. It must connect to MySQL (table called "Tasks") with SQLAlchemy and after that output all tasks from this table. All "tasks" have fields "StartDevelop" and "FinishDevelop" (DateTime fields). So my task is to output two buttons next to every name of "task". They must work with MySQL and send current time.
How can I connect two buttons to every row and connect all of them to python's script?

## Example:

task1(string), AcceptTask1(button), CompleteTask1(button)
task2(string), AcceptTask2(button), CompleteTask2(button)
task3(string), AcceptTask3(button), CompleteTask3(button)
task4(string), AcceptTask4(button), CompleteTask4(button)
...
where number of tasks is accepted from datebase.

## Code I made

I made dictionary, where key is task.Id and value is form(with string fields and two buttons). I also using field.descriptions to output/not output them.

```
@app.route('/database', methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def database():
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    tasks = Tasks.query.filter(current_user.Id == Tasks.Developer or current_user.Id == Tasks.Reviewer).paginate(page, app.config['TASKS_PER_PAGE'], False)
    forms = dict()

    for task in tasks.items:
        forms[task.Id] = DataBaseForm()
        forms[task.Id].set_values(task,current_user)



class DataBaseForm(FlaskForm):
    eord = StringField()
    task = StringField()
    assign_date = DateTimeField()
    type = StringField()
    accept_date = DateTimeField()
    accepted = SubmitField(label = 'Submit', description = 'Submit')
    comment = StringField()
    completed = SubmitField(label = 'Submit', description = None)

    def set_values(self, task, user):
        self.eord.description = task.course.Name
        self.task.description = task.Name
        self.assign_date.description = task.Created

        if (user.Id == task.Developer):
            if(task.EndDevelop):
                self.accept_date.description = task.EndDevelop
                self.accepted.description = ""
            else:
                self.accepted.description = 'Submit'
                self.comment.description = 'Comment'

        if (user.Id == task.Reviewer):
            if(task.EndReview):
                self.accept_date.description = task.EndReview
                self.accepted.description = ""
            else:
                self.accepted.description = 'Submit'
                self.comment.description = 'Comment'

        if(task.EndReview and task.EndDevelop):
            self.completed.description = 'Complete'
```

Comment: Your question is too broad to get a meaningful answer. Try to narrow your problem down to _specific_ questions, see if those questions have been answered, and if not, ask them.

Comment: As you are looking to render a form with many identical forms for all the different tasks, I'd suggest looking at a [`FieldList` of `FormFields`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30121763/how-to-use-a-wtforms-fieldlist-of-formfields). Then you need to return the form from your view, render it with a template, handle the `POST` return of the form data and update the database.