# Flask - Unable use validators in SubForms

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

My point is the following :

**I have a FieldList input with FloatFields on it.
But the validators in those nested fields doesn't run.**

The `NumberRange` works fine when I have a basic form.
But when I have a nested form, the `wtforms.validators.NumberRange` triggers the following error :

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'FloatField' and
>   'int'

I don't know why does that errors occurs ?

**Here is my main file :**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import FloatField, SubmitField, StringField, FieldList, FormField
from wtforms.validators import NumberRange


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret'

class mySubForm(FlaskForm):
    class Meta:
        csrf = False
    mySubField = FloatField(validators=[NumberRange(min=-100, max=100)])

class myForm(FlaskForm):
    myField = FieldList(FormField(mySubForm))
    mySubmit = SubmitField("Save")


@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def home():
    form = myForm()

    xLabels = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]

    for x in xLabels:
        subForm = mySubForm()
        form.myField.append_entry(subForm)

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash("success")

    return render_template("draft.html", form=form)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port="5000" ,debug=True)
```

**Here is my template :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .error{border-color: red;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <form method="POST" action="/">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

        {% for field in form.myField %}
          {% if field.mySubField.errors %}
            {{ field.mySubField(class="error") }}
            {% for error in field.mySubField.errors %}
              <span>{{ error }}</span>
            {% endfor %}
          {% else %}
            {{ field.mySubField.data }}
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

        {{ form.mySubmit() }}
      </form>

      {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=False) %}
        {% if messages %}
          {% for message in messages %}
            <p>{{ message }}</p>
          {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
      {% endwith %}
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This seems quite a complete answer regarding FieldLists: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30179649/10180115

Comment: It is a different topic. The validate_on_submit() succeeded. My point is about the validators execution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `append_entry` doesn't accept a field, it accepts raw data, so the validation fails because it's comparing a number to a `FloatField`.

Passing it a field is also why you're having to use `mySubField.data` in the template instead of simply `mySubField()`, because as it is, `mySubField` is rendering yet another field, the one you passed it.

To fix it, you can do something like

```py
form.myField.append_entry({'mySubField': some_number})
```

Which, as mentioned above, would allow you to fix the template too:

```
{% else %}
  {{ field.mySubField() }}
{% endif %}
```

As an aside, you might want to encase the `add_entry` logic in a conditional so it only happens in `GET` requests, otherwise you'll be adding new entries every time you submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Luis, here is the the working code :

**The my main file :**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, request
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import FloatField, SubmitField, StringField, FieldList, FormField
from wtforms.validators import NumberRange


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret'


class myForm(FlaskForm):
    myField = FieldList(FloatField(validators=[NumberRange(min=-100, max=100)]))
    mySubmit = SubmitField("Save")


@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def home():
    form = myForm()

    xLabels = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]

    if request.method == 'GET':
        for x in xLabels:
            form.myField.append_entry(data=42)

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash("success")

    return render_template("drat.html", form=form)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port="5000" ,debug=True)
```

**The template :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .error{border-color: red;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <form method="POST" action="/">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

        {% for field in form.myField %}
          {% if field.errors %}
            <br>{{ field(class="error") }}
            {% for error in field.errors %}
              <span><br>{{ error }}</span>
            {% endfor %}
          {% else %}
            <br>{{ field }}
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

        <br>{{ form.mySubmit() }}
      </form>

      {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=False) %}
        {% if messages %}
          {% for message in messages %}
            <p>{{ message }}</p>
          {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
      {% endwith %}
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```