# validate_on_submit() failing when receiving jQuery extended form with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask, flask-wtforms

#### What I'm trying to do

I have a static from with partially dynamic functionality, where you can add more `<input>` fields to add tags upon clicking a button.

#### The problem

My form is using WTForms templating for all static form fields and  `<input>` fields, generated with jQuery, based upon this [great answer from nsfyn55](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23921980/5476399), to add more tags.

The front-end works great, but I'm stuck on the validation in python, where `validate_on_submit()` keeps failing for an unknown reason.

I suspect it has something to do with the mixed use of templating and the jQuery generated `<input>` fields, somehow ruining the validation for me.
Another reason could be me, not understanding [how to use AJAX with flask properly](https://medium.com/@doobeh/posting-a-wtform-via-ajax-with-flask-b977782edeee) and somehow mishandling the AJAX POST.

[MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

**app.py**

```
@app.route(BASEURL + '/new', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def new():

    form = Form()
    global metadata
    data = dict()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        keyword1 = request.form['keyword-1']
        keyword2 = request.form['keyword-2']
        keyword3 = request.form['keyword-3']

        keywords = []

        if keyword1: keywords.append(keyword1)
        if keyword2: keywords.append(keyword2)
        if keyword3: keywords.append(keyword3)

        data.update({
            'given_name': form.abstract.data,
            'family_name': form.description.data,

            'keywords': keywords,
        })
        filename = 'data.json'
        with open('data/' + filename, 'w') as file:
            file.write(json.dumps(metadata, indent=4, sort_keys=False))


class Form(FlaskForm):

    given_name = StringField()
    family_name = StringField()
```

**new.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>New</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/form.js') }}"></script>

</head>
<body>
<form  method='POST' action='{{ url_for('new') }}'>
    {{ form.csrf_token }}

    {% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
      <dl>
            {{ render_field(form.given_name) }}

            {{ render_field(form.family_name) }}

            <div id="keywordsTest"></div>

            <button onclick="keywordField()">+</button>


      </dl>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>




<script>
    var index = 0;
    function keywordField(){
        if(index<3){
            index+=1;

            $('<input>').attr({
                type: 'text',
                id: 'keyword-' + index ,
                name: 'keyword-' + index,
                placeholder: 'keyword' + index
            }).appendTo('#keywordsTest');
        }
        return false
    }
    $(keywordField)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**form.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').on('submit', function(event) {
        $.ajax({
            data : {
                keyword1 : $('#keyword-1').val(),
                keyword2 : $('#keyword-2').val(),
                keyword3 : $('#keyword-3').val()
            },
            type : 'POST',
            url : '/register/new'
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: "keyword1" != "keyword-1". The names you're giving to the parameters in AJAX don't match the names the server is expecting. (What you named the fields originally in the HTML is irrelevant in this case, it's the structure you define in the AJAX which matters. Try `data : {
                "keyword-1" : $('#keyword-1').val(),
                "keyword-2" : $('#keyword-2').val(),
                "keyword-3" : $('#keyword-3').val()
            },` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment by @ADyson explains a specific issue you are having which is that you should really change the code to:

```
$.ajax({
        data : {
            "keyword-1" : $('#keyword-1').val(),
            "keyword-2" : $('#keyword-2').val(),
            "keyword-3" : $('#keyword-3').val()
        },
```

But this doesn't really solve your core problem. You are using WTForms, presumably because you want to use its inherent server-side form validation library. At the moment your `Form` class is performing no validation so the line `form.validate_on_submit()` will do nothing. Insert the following:

```
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired
...
given_name = StringField(validators=[InputRequired()])
```

At least now you can test your code so it attempts to perform some basic validation service.

But here is another problem. Your `Form` class expects to process two form fields; `given_name` and `family_name`, but the data you `POST` via AJAX does not contain either of these two fields, in fact the data you are posting is specified as:

```
    data : {
            "keyword-1" : $('#keyword-1').val(),
            "keyword-2" : $('#keyword-2').val(),
            "keyword-3" : $('#keyword-3').val()
        },
```

And thats it - you do not automatically send the other form fields in you HTML becuase you have directly and explicitly specified the data here.

At its `core` level Flask routes receive an object called `request`. If you insert the line

```
def new():
    print("the data supplied in post request form is: ", request.form)
```

Then you can debug what you see in the transmitted data. What will happen in this request is that `form.validate_on_submit()` will fail with the error `{'given_name: ['This field is required.']}`. Even if you supply this field in the form it will error because you are not explicitly passing it. When you execute `form = Form()` the `form` is populated with data from the `request`.

Having fixed this your code will also suffer with `KeyError` because if some fields are optional, or the user has not added a second or third optional input field then:

```
keyword2 = request.form['keyword-2']
```

will not exist so instead try something like

```
keyword2 = request.form.get('keyword-2', None)
```

since that at least has an escape clause.

I appreciate that you did not necessarily want to use my suggested approach previously with Webargs instead of WTForms, but in your example here the inclusion of WTForms is serving absolutely no purpose (besides HTML rendering client side perhaps). When you are accessing the submitted values you are accessing them directly in `request.form`, which circumvents server side validation completely and makes `form=Form()` completely redundant.

## Simple Solution

If you know that you will look to acquire at most 3 keywords then you can pre-populate your form with hidden fields:

```
class Form(FlaskForm):
    given_name = StringField(validators=[InputRequired()], render_kw={'placeholder': 'Given Name'})
    family_name = StringField(render_kw={'placeholder': 'Surname'})
    keyword1 = StringField(validators=[Optional()], render_kw={'placeholder': 'k1'})
    keyword2 = StringField(validators=[Optional()], render_kw={'style': 'display:none;', 'placeholder': 'k2'})
    keyword3 = StringField(validators=[Optional()], render_kw={'style': 'display:none;', 'placeholder': 'k3'})
```

On your HTML display the forms as follows:

```
{{ form.given_name }}
{{ form.family_name }}
{{ form.keyword1 }} 
{{ form.keyword2 }} 
{{ form.keyword3 }}
```

Because of the `render_kw` only Keyword1 will be visible, but you can easily code some JS to click a button and change the display property from `none` on Keyword2 and Keyword3, similar to what you did above, although less so since it only needs to getElementById and set the style property.

When the `submit` is clicked you do not need to intercept it and perform an AJAX query (meaning 'form.js' can be completely removed), you can just POST as a regular form action.
WTForms will validate it according to your class and populate data as `form.keyword2.data` etc.

Comment: Heading home now, but testing this ASAP. TYVM for the detailed answer!

Comment: I had serious trouble getting a template  tag to accept Javascript.
For exmple I tried using the the following syntax `{{ render_field(form.abstract, onInput="TextCounter(this, 32)") }}`  characters in a text field, but the Function `TextCounter` is not coming into effect.
`

Comment: edit: you talked about css, not JS, but still. CSS in templates is another problem.

Comment: did you try `oninput` rather than `onInput`? You can also pass the addition as a render_kw from the `FlaskForm`... `render_kw={'oninput': "TextCounter()"}` but this decouples your server and JS so is not maintainable/advisable. I would instead recommend using  the pure javascript method of adding event listeners: `document.getElementById("keyword1").addEventListener("oninput", function(){\\do something});`

Comment: Besides, I'm using extensive validation with WTForms, I just deleted it because I didn't want to overload the question.

Also, Yes, the event listeners where a great idea!

Comment: Implemented all the changes you suggested (including removing form.js) and it workes like a charm, TY!